# Redirection Stateful pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using stateful in kubernetes.
I write an application which will have leader and follower (using Go)
Leader is for writing and reading.
Follower is just for reading.

In the application code, I used "http.Redirect(w, r, url, 307)" function to redirect the writing from follower to leader.

if I use a jump pod to test the application (try to access the app to read and write), my application can work well, the follower can redirect to the leader

```
kubectl run -i -t --rm jumpod --restart=Never --image=quay.io/mhausenblas/jump:0.2 -- sh
```

But when I deploy a service (to access from outside).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-name
spec:
  selector:
    app: app-name
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9876
```

And access to application by this link:

```
curl -L -XPUT -T /tmp/put-name localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/service-name/proxy/
```

Because service will randomly select a pod each time we access to the application. When it accesses to leader, it work well (no problem happen), But if it accesses to the follower, the follower will need to redirect to leader, I met this error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pod-name.svc-name.default.svc.cluster.local
```

What I tested:

- I can use this link to access when I used jump pod
- I accessed to per pod, look up the DNS. I can find the DNS name by "nslookup" command
- I tried to fix the IP of leader in my code. In my code, the follower will redirect to a IP (not a domain like above). But It still met this error:

  ```
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.244.1.71 port 9876: No route to host
  ```

Anybody know this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order for pod DNS to work you must create headless service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-name-headless
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: app-name
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9876
```

And then in StatefulSet spec you must refer to this service:

```
spec:
  serviceName: svc-name-headless
```

Read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id

Alternatively you may specify what particular pod will be selected by Service like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-name
spec:
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: pod-name-0
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9876
```

Comment: Thank you. I used head-less service when I deploy my stateful application. I think the problem is not here. Because DNS look up can work well and I can redirect when I use jump pod

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing your cluster services from outside, a DNS names reserved normally for inner cluster use (e.g. pod-name.svc-name.default.svc.cluster.local) are not recognized by clients (e.g. Web browser).

**Context**:
 
You are trying to expose access to PODs, controlled by StatefullSet with service of ClusterIP type

**Solution**:
Change ClusterIP (assumed by default when not specified) to NodePort or LoadBalancer

Comment: I changed my service to NodePort, and access to my application (curl localhost:30036), but this error still happens when it unluckily access to the follower.

Comment: Localhost won't work, use <ext_node_ip>:30036 (external IP address of any of your nodes), and remember to open this port on firewall.

Comment: Sorry, how can I "open this port on firewall"? can you help me. Thank you

Comment: Whether you need to open port on firewall or not, depends on where you Kubernetes cluster is living, btw. can you update it in your post (is it managed/hosted, on-prem, turnkey cloud solution, etc.). Treat it optionally, or best consult this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/